# how we can tune this Delete query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Justin, As per your suggestion, here i added loop..

Is there anyway we can tune this procedure ? I have n't tested yet.

Here we are just deleting the records from master and child table prior to 90days history records. 
Assume that tables have more than 20k records are there to delete. and here i put commit for each 5k records.. Please letme know if i am wrong here ?

```
create or replace 
Procedure PURGE_CLE_ALL_STATUS 
 ( days_in IN number ) 
  IS 
  LV_EXCEPTIONID NUMBER;    
i number := 0;  


cursor s1 is 
        select EXCEPTIONID 
          from EXCEPTIONREC --- master table 
          where TIME_STAMP < (sysdate -days_in); 

BEGIN  

for c1 in s1 loop

     delete from EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY   -- child table 
     where EXCEPTIONID =c1.EXCEPTIONID ; 

     delete from EXCEPTIONREC 
     where EXCEPTIONID =c1.EXCEPTIONID; 

     i := i + 1;              

     if i > 5000 then      
      commit;         
      i := 0;      
     end if;  

end loop;  


commit;      

close S1; 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '|| 
                                      SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM); 
END; 
/
```

Comment: You have a cursor but no loop.  Are you really guaranteed that `c1` will never return more than 1 row (or, that if it returns multiple rows, that you don't care which row you fetch)?  If this procedure is only deleting one row per call, is the procedure itself being called in a loop:?

Comment: Justin, i added loop in my original post. Yes Cursor s1 will return more than one row (may 20k +). i need to delete 20k records from tables if cursor return 20k. but make sure after each 5k records, we need to put commit..

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You are executing 20000+ individual DELETE statements, rather than a single one. SQL is a set-based language. Operating in sets will always be vastly better than looping over individual rows.

Comment: Can some one please modify my procedure to run effectively..

Comment: Why do you want to commit every 5000 rows?

Answer (score 3):

instead of cursor .. you can directly give the condition in delete statement..

like below-

```
create or replace
Procedure PURGE_CLE_ALL_STATUS
 ( days_in IN number )
  IS
  LV_EXCEPTIONID NUMBER;   

BEGIN    

     delete from EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY   -- child table
     where EXCEPTIONID = -- (1)
          (select EXCEPTIONID
          from EXCEPTIONREC --- master table
          where TIME_STAMP < (sysdate -days_in));

     delete from EXCEPTIONREC
     where EXCEPTIONID = --(2)
          (select EXCEPTIONID
          from EXCEPTIONREC --- master table
          where TIME_STAMP < (sysdate -days_in));

commit;     
end if;
close c1;
END;
/
```

I fully agree with  Justin Cave .. he gave very good point .. 
if you are getting multiple rows from your cursor .. you can use `in` in place of `=` at (1) and (2).

Comment: Thanks for your response, basically i used cursor because of i have 10000s of records in both master and child tables. So they want to commit for each 5000 records. So how i can loop through each 5k records and apply commit ?

Comment: Why do you want to delete in chunks of 5000 records?

Comment: Becos after every 5k records they need commit.

Comment: But why? Is it because what you've got right now is so slow and you dont want to lock rows for longer than needed?

Answer (score 0):

> > > "delete records from master and child table prior to 90days history records "

To get full performance benefit , you shall implement partition table. of courser this change in design but may not change your application.

your use case is to delete data on regular basis. You try creating daily or weekly partition which will store the new data in newer partition & drop the older partition regularly.

Current way of deleting will have performance bottle neck, since you trying to delete data older than 90 days. let us say there 10,000 record per day, then by 90th day there will be 90*10000. locating & deleting few records from 90 million record will be always will be slow & create some other lock problem.